# Angular MatDialog appends to HTML instead of showing as a popup

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-material

I am following on an Angular MatDialog tutorial on Youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJJ_NDqvuCk) and did exactly the same as instructed. However, the popup seems not working properly. how can i make the popup shows in the middle of the screen instead of appending to the bottom of HTML

[image: How it shows]

[image: Code where dialog is implemented]

[image: Component template of dialog]

Comment: My dialog just keeps appending to the bottom of HTML.

Comment: Add code instead of images

Answer (score 4):

Did you import a theme?

Add the following line to `styles.css`/`styles.scss`/your main CSS file:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue solved by add themes into angular.json

```
{
 "project": {
  ...
  "architect": {
   "build": {
    ...
    "options": {
    "styles": [
     "src/styles.scss",
     "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
     ...
    ]
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this for global css while installing angular-material:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Make sure angular version compatible with it. [It's working for me as:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nqiV.png)